# Activity inheritance in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an activity in my Android project which is not used in the interface by itself, but rather it is extended by two child activities like this:

```
class ParentActivity extends Activity {
...
}

class LeftActivity extends ParentActivity {
...
} 

class RightActivity extends ParentActivity {
...
}
```

Can I not declare ParentActivity in the Android manifest? Because seemingly it works fine without it.

Comment: yeah. You should declare activities you are going to start. If activity not in manifest, it can recieve intent and get started.

Comment: You should declare activities you are going to start. if u clean the project and run it. it will crash i think.just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your android Manifest, you need to register the activities those actually are started from somewhere else or have a launch in any manner. Whether it is an Activity or a Service you can make the parent-child relationship but **need to declare only the activity or service that is actually being used**

if it not used whether it is parent activity or child no need to declare in Android manifest.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I not declare ParentActivity in the Android manifest? Because
>   seemingly it works fine without it.

No it doesn't requires to declare ParentActivity into manifest, until you launch/ show ParentActivity on UI.

In detail

If your need is only to show LeftActivity or RightActivity on UI, for eg

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LeftActivity.class)); // OR
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RightActivity.class));
```

Then you no need to declare ParentActivity into manifest.

But, when your need is to show ParentActivity on UI, for eg

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentActivity.class));
```

then you have to declare ParentActivity into manifest.

Comment: how would one test that, as by Espresso? (and it's still valid at the of the decade, right?)

Comment: @Phlip Yes this is still valid. So if you want to test only ParentActivity then you can add manifest (and add this class into that manifest) for test only. Other way is to test methods of ParentActivity into testcases of Childs

Comment: What would the ActivityTestRule<> calls look like? Would they use  ActivityTestRule<ParentActivity> or ActivityTestRule<ChildActivity>

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support Multiple Inheritance , i guess that is why it has been done. Created 
ParentActivity as super class . You can declare it in Manifest there would not be any issue.